# How to get child document from a collection in mondodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have created a collection which has sub collection data. I want to filter from sub collection with a key.

Here is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5758098356e3930537af15dd"),
    "manpower_data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5758098356e3930537af15de"),
            "created" : ISODate("2016-06-08T12:03:15.387Z"),            
            "designation" : "Visiting Evaluator",            
            "evaluatorContactNumber" : "987654321",            
            "evaluatorName" : "Dumy User1",
            "dealerCodeFor" : "ZSAE876",
            "region" : "Gurgaon"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5758098356e3930537af15de"),
            "created" : ISODate("2016-06-08T12:03:15.387Z"),            
            "designation" : "Resident Evaluator",            
            "evaluatorContactNumber" : "987654321",            
            "evaluatorName" : "Dumy User2",
            "dealerCodeFor" : "ZSAE877",
            "region" : "Delhi"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this query

`db.mycollection.find({"manpower_data.dealerCodeFor":"ZSAE876"});`

It returns me all two sub document but I want to get only those `manpower data` which has matching `dealerCodeFor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter array elements, query `projection` phase with `$elemMatch` need to be executed. Please see example below:

```
db.collection.find({
    "manpower_data.dealerCodeFor" : "ZSAE876"
}, {
    manpower_data : {
        $elemMatch : {
            dealerCodeFor : "ZSAE876"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It works. Thank you :)

Comment: NOTE:- This will only return first matching object from the array. If there are multiple you won't get them all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$filter` of `aggregate-mongodb` to achieve this.

Try the following:-

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    "$match": {"manpower_data.dealerCodeFor":"ZSAE876"}
},
{
    "$project": {
        "manpower_data": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$manpower_data",
                "as": "o",
                "cond": {  
                    "$eq": ["$$o.dealerCodeFor", "ZSAE876"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

By running the above query, `manpower_data` will return only the objects, which matches your condition.

EDIT:-

For version less than `2.6.x`, try following query:-

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    "$match": {"manpower_data.dealerCodeFor":"ZSAE876"}
},  
{ "$unwind": "$manpower_data" },
{ 
    "$match": {"manpower_data.dealerCodeFor":"ZSAE876"}
},
{
    "$group": {
        "$_id": "$_id",
        "manpower_data": { "$push": "$manpower_data" }
    }
}])
```

Comment: @Shrebanee I run the above query but gave me error `uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$filter'",
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0
}`

Comment: why aggregate here? is a shotgun to kill a little fly :-),

Comment: @profesor79 I thought, if there are multiple objects inside the array, matching the query, projecting all those objects can be done through aggregate.

Comment: @AnuranjanPandey forgot to mention, this can be used only with mongodb version 3.2.x. What is the version you are using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

Comment: @AnuranjanPandey Edited my answer with the query that can help you.